# rails and namespaced models issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, models

Using rails 3/3.1 I want to store invoices with their items (and later more associations like payments, etc…).

So in a first approach I set up the models like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_items
end

class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

And the routes likes this:

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :invoice_items
end
```

I chose InvoiceItem instead of Item because I already have a model named Item and I somehow want to namespace the model to invoices. But this name has the huge disadvantage that one has to use invoice.invoice_items instead of a intuitive invoice.items. Also the generated url helpers look real ugly, for example "new_invoice_invoice_item_path(invoice)" (notice the double invoice_invoice).

So I changed to namespaced models like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :class_name => "Invoice::Item"
end

class Invoice::Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

And the routes likes this:

```
resources :invoices do
  resources :items, :module => "invoice"
end
```

Now the assocation is named nicely and also the url helpers look pretty. But I can't use dynamic urls (ex. [:new, invoice, :item]) anymore, because the controller is set to "invoice_item" instead of "invoice/item".

I wonder how other people solve this problem and what I'm doing wrong. Or is this simply a bug in rails 3.0.7/ 3.1.rc?

EDIT:
Sorry, I seems I didn't correctly express my concern. My model Item is not related to Invoice::Item. Order::Item is also not related to Item nor Invoice::Item. An Invoice::Item can only belong to one invoice. An Order::Item can only belong to an Order. I need to namespace - but why doesn't rails properly support namespacing out of the box? Or what am I doing wrong with namespacing?

Corin

Comment: Just wondering why you want to namespace the Item model?

Comment: Because I have another model named Item already. Item is a real generic name and can be used in many contexts: Invoice::Item, Order::Item, …

Comment: Why wouldn't an invoice `has_many :items` ? It only seems logical to me that if I'm buying items, that's what would appear on my invoice. also, don't your items belong to many invoices? Surely you wouldn't have a singular invoice. You might look at a HABTM relationship.

Comment: @gucki if you're wanting Invoices and Orders to all be able to have items it sounds like you might want to either investigate polymorphic associations or a `has_many :through` setup. I'd venture to say that an Order `has_many :items, :through => :invoices` [Look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I agree with Caley, has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many => :through would be the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I seems I didn't correctly express what I have in mind. Model Item is *not* related to Invoice::Item. Order::Item is also not related to Item nor Invoice::Item. An Invoice::Item can only belong to one invoice. An Order::Item can only belongs to an Order. I need to namespace - but why doesn't rails properly support namespacing out of the box? Or what am I doing wrong with namespacing?

Answer (score 0):

If an order item and an invoice item are not the same object in the real world then I would name them differently rather than trying to namespace, for example `OrderItem` and `InvoiceItem` - this will keep things clearer as your codebase grows and avoid the need to make sure you use the right namespace everywhere you reference an Item.

Comment: This is the first approach I took (as written above). But it results in bad names in several placaes, like assocations, routes, path helpers etc. So this is not a practical solution imo.

Comment: That's true, but you can always tidy these up before displaying to the user.